# Can't call a function from CountDownTimer object. What am I missing?

Tags: kotlin, class, object, random, timer

I'm going through Googles Kotlin Compose tutorials. One of the tasks is to build a game where you [unscramble words](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-test-viewmodel?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-4-pathway-1%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-test-viewmodel#5). After completing it, I tried to improve the game on my own, and just can't figure out how to add a countdown timer to it. I want the program to skip a word when time runs out.

I'm a programming noob, it's not quite clear to me yet how classes and objects work and how they differ from functions.

The code for the timer at the moment:

```
object Timer: CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onFinish() {
        skipWord() // <<----------- **Unresolved reference: skipWord**
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in my code I have:

```
class GameViewModel : ViewModel() {

//....

fun skipWord() {    // <<---------------- Function that skips to the next word
    updateGameState(_uiState.value.score)
    updateUserGuess("")
}

//.....

private fun pickRandomWordAndShuffle(): String {
    // Continue picking up a new random word until you get one that hasn't been used before
    if (currentLanguage == "English") {
        currentWord = engWords.random()
    } else {
        currentWord = finWords.random()
    }

    setPointAmount()
    Timer.start() // <<---------------Start a new countdown for a new word.

    if (usedWords.contains(currentWord)) {
        return pickRandomWordAndShuffle()
    } else {
        usedWords.add(currentWord)
        return shuffleCurrentWord(currentWord)
    }
}

}
```

Also, a separate problem: the .random() always uses the same seed and picks the same words to unscramble.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
object Timer: CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
...
```

to

```
val timer = object: CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
...
```

and put in into your GameViewModel class.

To solve random issue provide some seed to Random object, like:

```
var myRandom = Random(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

and then

```
currentWord = engWords[myRandon.nextInt(engwords.lastIndex)]
```